# How to see duration actively how much time pressing button on android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my code. I want to see actively how much second press button also I want to do this lively. Textview should be update every second if I am pressing button.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText("Time: "+timer);
                timer++;
            }
        };
        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    while(!button.isPressed())
                    {
                        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
                    }

                }
                else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

By the way this code **gone be crash**, because while loop doesn't work the way i want. If I don't use any loop, textview just only updated 1 times. I want it updated every second. Thanks to everyone who will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. The method belongs to handler post() which start runnable where it is, save me from this problem. There is the code.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                handler = new Handler();
                runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
                        textView.setText("Time: "+timer);
                        timer++;

                    }
                };
                handler.post(runnable);

            }
            else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When down event start, run method start with it. Run method is over 1 second later then out of it. If 1 second later still pressing button, handler never stop runnable so runnable events start again and again. This is simple runnable and handler loop.